# SQL Filter combinations of columns

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I keep only one combination of the values of two columns?

I have a table(query result) like:

```
ID1 |ID2 |SomeNotImportantComun
1   |2   |A
2   |1   |A
3   |4   |C
```

For row 1 and 2 the combination of ID1 and ID2 is the same [1,2]. I want to keep ony one of the rows.

```
ID1 |ID2 |SomeNotImportantComun
2   |1   |A
3   |4   |C
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Can you have more than two duplicates?  Is the sample data representative?

Comment: WHICH row do you want to keep, when you have duplicates? Alexej suggests you can use "order by" - but perhaps your conditions aren't as simple as ordering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with something like this:

```
with test(ID1, ID2, SomeNotImportantComun) as
(
select 1 ,2, 'A' from dual union all
select 2 ,1, 'A' from dual union all
select 3 ,4, 'C' from dual
)
select id1, id2, SomeNotImportantComun
from (
        select id1, id2, SomeNotImportantComun,
               row_number() over ( partition by least(id1, id2), greatest(id1, id2) order by id1 desc, id2 desc) as rank
        from test
     )
where rank = 1
```

Here you keep only one row for any combination of IDs; you can decide which one you want to keep by editing the `order by` clause

Answer (score 1):

Use this query to find rows which won't be needed when a symmetric pair exists.

```
select t1.*
from tablename t1
join tablename t2 on t1.id1 = t2.id2 and t1.id2 = t2.id1 
and t1.somenotimpcol = t2.somenotimpcol
where t1.id1 < t1.id2
```

Then use `minus` to eliminate these rows from the original table/query result.

```
select * from tablename
minus
select t1.*
from tablename t1
join tablename t2 on t1.id1 = t2.id2 and t1.id2 = t2.id1 
and t1.somenotimpcol = t2.somenotimpcol
where t1.id1 < t1.id2
```